# awk ^word$ matches whitespace unexpectedly, how to exclude?

Tags: regex, awk

I'm extracting sections from a text file which looks like

```
    blah blah
end
config router bgp
    set as 123
    config neighbor
        edit 1.2.3.4
            set remote-as 321
        next
    end
    blah blah
end
config router blah
    blah blah
```

using

```
awk '/^config router bgp$/,/^end$/' myfile
```

which returns

```
config router bgp
    set as 123
    config neighbor
        edit 1.2.3.4
            set remote-as 321
        next
    end
```

my problem is that the ^end$ regex matches the indented "end" for config neighbor which has leading whitespace, so I'm not getting the entire section.

How can I force the ^end$ regex to not match on a line with (leading) white space?

Comment: I can't reproduce your symptom - neither on OS X 10.9.1 nor on Ubuntu 12.04 - what OS / awk version are you running? Does your input file really look as described?

Comment: OS - Windows XP. awk is part of a NuTCROOT / MKS toolkit version 7.5

Comment: File format is as described, checked using notepad++. indented lines have leading space characters and none trailing. newline character is \n not \r\n, that shouldn't matter

Comment: If your toolkit has vim or you have gvim installed can you provide the response to `:set ff?` of the input file?  ( I'm wondering if file-format is responsible for the strangeness )

Comment: notepad++ says unix for file format, looks clean with Show All Characters, vim not present. I've done plenty of searching etc on these files before. This awk has some quirks but not sure how to work around this.

Comment: I suggest you install cygwin and use gnu awk provided therein. Good luck

Comment: I don't have the option, but point taken. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work around if there are always two `end` after `bgp`:

```
awk '/^config router bgp$/ {f=2} f; f && /end/ {f--}' myfile
config router bgp
    set as 123
    config neighbor
        edit 1.2.3.4
            set remote-as 321
        next
    end
    blah blah
end
```

Comment: I like your thinking. Unfortunately the number of indented ends is variable.

Comment: But I can see your method coming in handy at some stage. I like a lot. (I keep hitting enter expecting a line feed and getting a post).

Comment: I'd vote it up as useful but I don't have enough reputation. It isn't strictly the correct answer. Sorry, sending karma instead?

Comment: No problem.  You should be able to click the with check mark to the left of the post to accept.  You should try GNU Awk for windows.